# Using Mysql Variables to count Rows does not work when adding Joined Table to Order Clause

Tags: mysql, variables, join

Alright I put "Limit" in quotes because I learned the fix for this is to not use the Limit clause but to use custom variables. I would like to get the number of at bats for baseball player based on the last 10 game dates he has played.

For example purposes, have tables set up like.

table: at_bats
game_id | batter_id | at_bats

table: schedule
id | game_date

at_bats.game_id and schedule.id are linked.

I have tried to do this on my own and got to this point. This actually works in terms of given a result that has the rowNum increasing by 1 each time.

```
SELECT t1.batter_id , t1.ab , t2.game_date 
   , @num := if(@batter = t1.batter_id , @num + 1 , 1) as rowNum
   , @batter := t1.batter_id as dummy
FROM mlb_batting_stats t1
LEFT JOIN mlb_schedule t2
   ON t2.id = t1.game_id
WHERE t1.batter_id IN (547180,572821,545361)
ORDER BY t1.batter_id
```

The problem is I want to order it by t2.game_date DESC so I can limit the number of games to 5. But when I add...

```
SELECT t1.batter_id , t1.ab , t2.game_date 
   , @num := if(@batter = t1.batter_id, @num + 1 , 1) as rowNum
   , @batter := t1.batter_id as dummy
FROM mlb_batting_stats t1
LEFT JOIN mlb_schedule t2
   ON t2.id = t1.game_id
WHERE t1.batter_id IN (547180,572821,545361)
ORDER BY t1.batter_id,t2.game_date DESC
```

I added the t2.game_date DESC. But now the results are ordered in the correct way but the rowNum is always 1. Once I know how to get the rowNum to increase with this, I can work my way to adding the sum and group by parts. But I simply can't get the result set to return the rows numbered correctly once I add the t2.game_date DESC.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As a side note you  need to declare the variables or use cross join `FROM mlb_batting_stats t1,(select @num:=0,@batter:= 0)x`

Comment: yeah or @num might start at 72 the next time

Comment: Thanks guys, how would you add that in with the join? I tried it and it says t1.game_id column does not exist.